# Gradle DSL method not found: 'deleteAllActions()'

Tags: android, android-studio

I cloned [this](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture) project from github and imported it using android studio but after doing all the rounds I'm getting this error

`ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'deleteAllActions()'`

Can anyone help me remove this error and build the project well?

Answer (score 5):

You should update the version of the Retrolambda plugin. Currently, that would be `3.7.1`.

So in your project's `build.gradle` file, make sure that you have this line:

`classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.1'`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using below dependency for multiple image selection functionality.

`react-native-multiple-image-picker`

then remove the below line from build.gradle of the same library.

`apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to open the project on Android Studio 3.4.x, then update your android studio to 3.5.1 and re-clone the same project. I had the same issue and after updating, it built the project successfully!

Edit: This is happening specifically when gradle is updated to 5.4.1

To stop this from happening, change this line in`build.gradle` file :

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'`

To this :

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'`

And change this line in `gradle-wrapper.properties` :

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`

To this :

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2.1-bin.zip`

Then sync and it will successfully sync the project

Answer (score -1):

Remove dependency `me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda` from `build.gradle` in `data` module.